# Как масштабировать картинку в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

Tags: java, android

Рисую картинку и вывожу вот так:

```
// рисую в отдельном классе
...
Canvas canvas = main_picture.beginRecording(w,h);
canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100, point);
...
main_picture.endRecording();
....
// Вывожу в MainActivity на imgView
canvas.drawPicture(main_picture);
imgView.invalidate();
```

Если разрешение экрана на устройстве очень большое, то все нарисованные линии становятся плохо различимыми. 
Можно ли уменьшать или увеличивать dpi в зависимости от разрешения экрана? Или это решается каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Храните несколько вариантов картинок. Подгружайте ту или иную в зависимости от разрешения и уже её масштабируйте, если необходимо.

Comment: Можно увеличить ширину линий в зависимости от разрешения экрана;)

Comment: Хранить варианты картинок нельзя, т.к. все они создаются в памяти и всегда разные. Ширину линий менять тоже не вариант, т.к. помимо линий еще грузятся пиктограммы с неизменяемой шириной и высотой. Нужно что-то делать с масштабирование картинки целиком, но за счет изменения dpi.